# How to continously append a 16 bit integer to a fixed 8 bit array

Tags: c, arrays, integer, memcpy

I'm trying to store ADC values of type `uint16_t` to a 32KB `uint8_t` as I'd like to write the data to an SD Card. Currently I'm struggling with how to copy my converted 16 bit integer into my buffer.

My code looks like this:

```
#define SD_WRITE_BUF_SIZE 32768 //32KB

uint16_t adc_value;  // holds the adc Converted value
uint8_t adc_conv_value[2]; // array to store the 8bit conversion of adc_value;

UINT bytesWritten;

int adc_callback_counter = 0;

uint8_t sd_buf_write[SD_WRITE_BUF_SIZE];

int main void
{
    Mount_SD_CARD(); // Mount SD Card
    Open_SD_CARD_write(); // create file and open for writing
    Start_ADC_Conversion(); // Start ADC Conversion;

    while (1)
    {

        if(adc_callback_counter >= (32768/2))
        {
            write_res = f_write(&myFile, sd_buf_write, SD_WRITE_BUF_SIZE, &bytesWritten);
             if(write_res ==  FR_OK)
             {
                 // Stop ADC
                 ADC_Stop();
                 // reset counter 
                 adc_conv_counter = 0;               
                 // close file
                 f_close(&myFile);
        }

    }
}

ADC_Conversion_Callback()
{

    // convert to 2 8 bit values;
   adc_conv_value[0] = (adc_values & 0xFF);
   adc_conv_value[1] = (adc_values >> 8) & 0xFF;

   // How do I use memcpy to continously copy adc_conv_value to sd_buf_write
   memcpy(sd_buf_write, ???, sizeof(??));

   // Increment counter;
   adc_callback_counter++;      

}
```

In the `ADC_Conversion_Callback()` function, How do you continously append the `adc_conv_value` to `sd_buf_write` until the latter array is full?

Comment: Why wouldnt you just have an array of uint16_t that you'd write there?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala That's a good question actually. Not sure why I assumed I only had to write 8 bit integers.

Comment: @MaskedAfrican: Is the data you write to the SD card supposed to be "big endian" or "little endian", and does `uint16_t` have the desired endianness?

Comment: @Brendan at the minute, there is no requirement for endianess. I  was just mostly concerned with "how to write it" and not wasn;t worrying about the order in which the data should arrive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> // How do I use memcpy to continously copy adc_conv_value to
>   sd_buf_write
>
> ```
>    memcpy(sd_buf_write, ???, sizeof(??));
> ```

You could use `adc_callback_counter` variable which tells how many times `memcpy` has been called.

```
memcpy((char *)sd_buf_write + (sizeof (adc_conv_value) * adc_callback_counter), adc_conv_value, sizeof(adc_conv_value));
```

---

`(sizeof (adc_conv_value)* adc_callback_counter)` Because each time we are copying `sizeof (adc_conv_value)`, thus starting position will be `sd_buf_write + (sizeof (adc_conv_value) * adc_callback_counter)`

Comment: What if my sd_buf_write was `uint16_t` and I just wanted to copy `adc_conv_value` in directly? Would that basically be `memcpy(sd_buf_write + sizeof(adc_conv_value), &adc_conv_value, sizeof(adc_conv_value));`

Comment: Why do you think you need `memcpy` always? you could just do `sd_buf_write[adc_callback_counter] = adc_values` without any conversion.